# How to iterate in a list of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a simple code to ask for username and password, and match those information in a database. And if the username is not in the database I ask the user if he want's to sign up, and then add that information to the database.

Everything in the code works well. except when I add another user in the database.

In this code, if the user enters Bob and password test123, the user is identified in the database and the code exits. However, if they user enters Rolf, it's not identified and he's asked to signup.

How can I adjust the code to iterate over the whole database.

Code

---

```
database = [{"username": 'Bob', "Password": 'test123'},{"username": 'Rolf', "Password": "password2"}]

def askuser():
input_username = input("Please enter your username: ")
input_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
for user in database:
    if user["username"] == input_username and user["Password"] == input_password:
        print(f"username {input_username} is correct, welcome to the program")
        break
    else:
        choice = input(f"username {input_username} doesnt exist, do you want to sign up Y/n : ")
        choice.strip('')
        if choice == "Y":
            while True:
                    input_desireduser = input("Please enter your desired username: ")
                    input_desiredpass = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
                    input_desiredpassconf = input("Please enter your desired password again: ")
                    if (input_desiredpassconf != input_desiredpass):
                        print("Your passwords doesn't match, please enter them again !!")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Thank you, your account is created")
                        database.append({"username": input_desireduser, "Password": input_desiredpass})
                        break
        else:
            print("Thank you !!")
            break

return database

askuser()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the if/else even though there multiples problems.
Let's say I type Rudolph and the correct password.
1st loop : 
if Bob == Rudolph is False, hence it will execute the else part.

You'll have to loop over the list and gather a boolean using mybool = mybool or my condition.
then check afterward.

Is it mandatory to use a list of dictionaries ?
In this exemples it doesn't make sense.
Here is one without a list of dict

```
database = {'bob':'test123','Rudolph':'password'}
 defAskUser()
    input_username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    input_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    try:
        password = dataset[input_username]
        if password == input_password:
            print(f"username {input_username} is correct, welcome to the program")
    except KeyError:
        choice = input(f"username {input_username} doesnt exist, do you want to sign up Y/n : ")
        choice.strip('')
        if choice == "Y":
                    input_desireduser = input("Please enter your desired username: ")
                    input_desiredpass = input("Please enter your desired password: ")
                    input_desiredpassconf = input("Please enter your desired password again: ")
                    if (input_desiredpassconf != input_desiredpass):
                        print("Your passwords doesn't match, please enter them again !!")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Thank you, your account is created")
                        database.append({input_desireduser:input_desiredpass})
                        break
        else:
            print("Thank you !!")
            break
```